# drupal webform - credit card resubmit on admin edit

Tags: drupal, webforms, authorize.net, drupal-webform

I have a client who has a drupal website installation. On the site there is a form that allows unauthorized/anonymous users to submit a request for some official data of which there is a charge.

The problem is when the admin goes in to the website and fills in the some additional fields (used for office processing) the credit card charged again.

Is there a way to provide a save button for admins that does NOT charge? or have it only charge once - if it fails on web then admins can run it via other means.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to exactly understand issue but you can change form with an hook_form_alter : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x

So, it will allow you to modify form before rendering and maybe delete credit card service callback with condition on current user logged.

Something like

```
function MYMODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    global $user;
    if($form_id == 'my_credi_card_form_id' && $user->uid == 1){ 
         //superadmin or use user_has_role function for group of user with permissions
        // dump form structure to identify callback and after unset it from form
    }
}
```